# how to check specific tag is available is soup variable while crawling?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i want to crawl page with condition and check specific class is available in soup variable.
if that class is not available then get data from another class
how to do that using Beautifulsoup.
`if soup.find_all("p", class_="pgInfo"):
             PgInfo = soup.find_all("p", class_="pgInfo")
             for pi in PgInfo:
                          print pi.getText()
else:
             feaBnft = soup.find_all("ol", class_="featureBnft")
             for fea in feaBnft:
                         print fea.getText()`

I WANT TO FETCH DATA FOR FIRST CLASS AND IF FIRST NOT AVAILABLE THEN FETCH FOR SECOND CLASS. BUT 
this is code i wrote.but first if return empty so else doesn't get execute
how can i change code to check both conditions

Comment: You can check whether the result is empty, else use another tag.

Comment: yes result in first if condition is empty so it doesn't go to else loop

Comment: if soup.find_all("p", class_="pgInfo"):
             PgInfo = soup.find_all("p", class_="pgInfo")
             for pi in PgInfo:
                          print pi.getText()
else:
             feaBnft = soup.find_all("ol", class_="featureBnft")
             for fea in feaBnft:
                         print fea.getText()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if soup.find(class_='specific class'):
    do something
else:
    do someting
```

Comment: i do the same prints nothing code-if soup.find_all("p", class_="pgInfo"):
             PgInfo = soup.find_all("p", class_="pgInfo")
             for pi in PgInfo:
                          print pi.getText()
else:
             feaBnft = soup.find_all("ol", class_="featureBnft")
             for fea in feaBnft:
                         print fea.getText()

Comment: @user6414153 provide information in the question not in the comment, you should update you question .